# Add parameters to querystring when using pagingcontrol in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, pagination, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I use paging control of dnn for pagination:

```
<dnn:PagingControl id="ctlPagingControl" runat="server" Mode="PostBack"></dnn:PagingControl>
```

and it works. i want to show currentpage in the url when page is changed.

the url is now :
localhost/dnn/en-us/page/module.aspx

and i want to show: localhost/dnn/en-us/**currentpage/2**/page/module.aspx/ when go to page 2.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete Mode="PostBack" an then use QuerystringParams property of pagingControl.

and get currentpage from querystring.

it works

Answer (score 1):

Change `Mode` to `URL` to have the page numbers in the URL.